# While copying a file in netrw, why should I be in the directory where the file is located?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, netrw, filesystem

In netrw, I want to copy a file `/dir/subdir1/file.txt` to `/dir/subdir2`. For that, I do the following:

1. I mark the file `/dir/subdir1/file.txt`
2. I navigate up directory and mark `/dir/subdir2/` as target
3. While being in `/dir/`, I press `mc` and get the error:
   `(netrw) there are no marked files in this window (:help netrw-mf)`

However, If I navigate back to `/dir/subdir1/`, everything works fine. It seems like `mc` applies only to the files which are marked in the current directory. I find it inconvenient, and I would like to copy the files which are marked not in the current directory. Is it possible?

UPDATE (30 April):
I found out that the same behavior holds (unsurprisingly) for `mx` and `mz`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!